# Next.js dynamic routes using a different URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I am currently updating a React project to use Next.js. I've stumbled on a slight issue with Dynamic Routing which so far I can't find any solutions online.

I have a number of info pages that use the same component and display different content based on the slug. Using `react-router` these can be specified as follows:

```
path: /:infoPage(about-us|terms|privacy|contact|faqs)

/about-us, /terms, /privacy, /contact, /faqs
```

So far for Next.js, I thought I'd use a dynamic route as seen below. The only issue is that the URLs will now have `/infoPage/___` - `/infoPage/about-us`, `/infoPage/terms`.

```
/pages
   /infoPage
      /[infoPage].js
```

As a solution links can be updated using `as` with the proper URL:

```
<Link href="/infoPage/[infoPage]?infoPage=about-us" as="/about-us">
   <a>About Us</a>
</Link>
```

Whilst this works when clicking on a link, refreshing the page will end up a 404 page - since Next.js is not aware of any page as `/about-us`.

### Possible Solutions

- Use dynamic route `/pages/[infoPages].js`. Not quite sure if this is the ideal solution as it would most probably act like a fallback to any other page.
- I suppose I could have every page declared separately within `/pages` and import the same component in each page but it will be slightly repetitive.

  ```
  /pages
      /about-us.js
      /terms.js
      ...
  ```
- Keep `/infoPage/[infoPage].js` route, add redirects from client/server to the proper URL

I may be over thinking this, the second solution would not be the end of the world but I'm still wondering if there's a better solution.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try `[...infoPage].js` it's all in the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: I've just realised that I can use [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) to define the parameters of the dynamic route. So I can list the URLs required there.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for an answer to this question, here are two solutions you may consider.

### 1. Dynamic Route in `/pages` at root level

*Use Case: Pages using the same components with similar data (for example API call to get page content)*

If you have certain pages similar to each other at root level, you can create a dynamic route such as below:

```
/pages
   /[rootPage].js
```

Keep in mind that if these pages are using Static Site Generation, slugs need to declared using `getStaticPaths`.

[Further details on getStaticPaths here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation)

It is also important to note that predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes. Should a dynamic route have a slug the same as a predefined route, Next will always render the predefined route. So this approach can be risky at root level.

[Dynamic Routing Caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats)

### 2. Separate routes, one `getStaticProps` function

*Use Case: Pages require similar data/API calls but use different components*

You may opt to have routes for each page but use the same `getStaticProps` function.

Routes:

```
/pages
   /about-us.js
   /terms.js
```

`getStaticProps` helper function:

```
const getPageStaticProps = () => {
   return async (context) => {
      // generic logic here
   }
}
```

Page (`about-us.js`, `terms.js`):

```
// /pages/about-us.js
function AboutPage(props) {
   return <AboutComponent {...props} />
}

export const getStaticProps = getPageStaticProps()

---

// /pages/terms.js
function TermsPage(props) {
   return <TermsComponent {...props} />
}

export const getStaticProps = getPageStaticProps()
```

This can also be implemented using `getServerSideProps`.

---

I opted for the second solution as it felt safer and still benefitted from having code shared between different pages. Obviously there may be other solutions our there that can be used :)